# Any way to clean engine oil system following possible overheat?

Tags: engine, oil

I purchased a car with the intent of fixing it to sell again.  It required new fuel injectors, O2 sensors, plugs, cats, computer, etc.  Most problems stemmed from a buildup of oil on the exterior of the engine fouling one of the fuel injectors.  I fear that this may have overheated the engine internally also, causing the formation of oil sludge or coagulate.

Is there any way to treat the oil system to remove any coagulate that might have built up in there?  Short of removing and tearing apart the engine?  Also, the oil pan on this car is not easily drop-able.  It would require loosening the engine mounts,  and raising the engine to get clearance over a support.

## Note

To be clear, the engine is not overheating now, but I suspect that it might have to one degree or another in the past.  This is just a cautionary step I want to take prior to selling the vehicle now that it is fixed.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure if others would agree, so leaving this as a comment. In the past I've used diesel fuel in place of oil to clean out the engine. Diesel is a very low viscosity oil and flows very easily. It also has tons of detergent in it, so cleans really well. If you do go this route, do it before you change to a new filter on it, but after you've drained the oil. Also, after you've started the engine, run it at an idle ONLY. This will ensure you're not taxing the engine. This will clean a lot of gunk out of the oil passages.

Comment: This is/was common practice but do make sure you flush it thoroughly before putting the new oil in...